# Get messages between two numbers in Twilio

Tags: javascript, twilio

I am using client.messages.list to get SMS messages. I want to filter these **between** two numbers. For now I could only filter the messages as "from" *and then* as "to". I have to then append these lists & then sort (with dateSent) to figure out the exact sequence of messages.

```
let allMsgs = await client.messages.list({
      from: "111-222-3333",    // my business
      to: "444-555-6666",      // customer
      limit: 200,
    });
    
const incoming = await client.messages.list({
      from: "444-555-6666",    // customer
      to: "111-222-3333",      // my business
      limit: 200,
    });

// There are some more map functions here (not shown to keep it clean)

allMsgs.push(...incoming)
allMsgs.sort((a, b) => a.dateSent - b.dateSent); // Note: datesent is Unix time
```

I am trying to make it more performant.

Is there an easier way that I am missing? I have gone through the API [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource?code-sample=code-read-list-messages-matching-filter-criteria&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x)

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what the question is. What do you mean by "easier"? Do you want to do this in one API call?

Comment: @IanNewson - Correct. Is there one API call? Asking because Twilio has the "sorted by time" list.

Comment: are you asking for an api call to pull all message both incoming and outgoing ?

Comment: @A-Developer-Has-No-Name: That is correct. Both incoming & outgoing between 2 numbers. I have updated my question with hardcoded phone numbers to make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think ordering is the issue.
The filters provided on Twilio's API don't allow for more the one 'from' and one 'to'.
therefore you need to run 2 separate pulls to get all calls you are looking for.
It might be more performant to make one unfiltered api call to retrieve calls which will come sorted already and then filter using the filtering functionality of the language you are using

Comment: Yes. This seems to be the case. I want to avoid "unfiltered" pull because there could be many customers (many to's) and I may miss messages between the numbers I want. Thanks!